# more pythonic way to assign userInput to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input

I was assigned this problem for my college CS class.  Still new in the dictionaries and sets and coding in general.
So I am looking for a more pythonic way for the section of assigning userInput to a dictionary.  This works for my needs, but it would get tedious for anything more than this.
Yes, I have seen the other questions regarding this similar function from CodeAcademy, but those dont have the answer for my problem.
Thanks in advance for any input. Take care.

```
gradeBook = {
  "student1" : {
  "name": "Andy", 
  "homework": [90.0, 85.0, 78.0, 92.0], 
  "quizzes": [85.0, 87.0, 90.0, 75.0, 95.0], 
  "tests": [85.0, 65.0]
  },
"student2" : {
  "name": "Brad", 
  "homework": [88.0, 78.0, 86.0, 99.0], 
  "quizzes": [88.0, 82.0, 100.0, 74.0, 82.0], 
  "tests": [90.0, 92.0]
  }, 
"student3" : {
  "name": "Billy",
  "homework": [81.0, 79.0, 80.0, 50.0], 
  "quizzes": [80.0, 78.0, 95.0, 80.0, 84.0], 
  "tests": [95.0, 93.0]
  }}
for k, v in gradeBook.items():
  print()
  for k in v:
    print(k + ':', v[k])
print()

userInput = input("Which students' average would you like to view: \nAndy, Brad, or Billy? \n")
print()

#assigning userInput to a students dictionary
if userInput == "Andy":
  userInput1 = gradeBook["student1"]["homework"]
  userInput2 = gradeBook["student1"]["quizzes"]
  userInput3 = gradeBook["student1"]["tests"]
elif userInput == "Brad":
  userInput1 = gradeBook["student2"]["homework"]
  userInput2 = gradeBook["student2"]["quizzes"]
  userInput3 = gradeBook["student2"]["tests"]
else:
  userInput1 = gradeBook["student3"]["homework"]
  userInput2 = gradeBook["student3"]["quizzes"]
  userInput3 = gradeBook["student3"]["tests"]

def get_average(userInput):
  averageHW = sum(userInput1) / len(userInput1)
  averageQ = sum(userInput2) / len(userInput2)
  averageT = sum(userInput3) / len(userInput3)
  print(averageHW, averageQ, averageT) #normal average
  wAverageHW = averageHW * 0.10
  wAverageQ = averageQ * 0.30
  wAverageT = averageT * 0.60
  print(wAverageHW, wAverageQ, wAverageT) #weighted average

get_average(userInput)
```

Comment: Good job on your question. Too many undergrads post their homework without having given it a real try themselves, and lose out on really learning because of it. Let me know if you have any questions about my answer

Comment: Thank you. Sorry it took so long to reply.  Im still in the beginning phases of dictionaries and sets so any help is appreciated.

Comment: No worries. You should pick an answer and mark it as correct though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rekey your dictionary if you’re going to be doing lookups by student name.

```
gradebookByStudent = {gradebook[k][‘name’]: gradebook[k] for k in gradebook}

#get your student name via user input 

print(‘HW average is: ‘ + mean(gradebookByStudent[userInput][‘homework’]))
```

This gives you lookups at O(log(n))  worst case, average O(1) vs O(n) when you iterate through your dictionary, a significant time savings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple unpacking to itterate through your dictionary
`for key, student in gradebook.items():
    If student ['name'] == userinput:
        getaverage(student)`

Something like this is more more pythonic allows you to go through the key and value parts of a dictionary simultaneously